# NGINX Lua search/replace in request body

Tags: nginx, lua

Due to some legacy software I need to alter the body of a SOAP request. It uses SOAP-ENV for the namespace while it needs to become just 'soap':

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Should become:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
```

Though it should not matter, for the legacy software it does. To at least make a quick fix for now I though about a search/replace in the request body. Nginx runs as a webserver before the system, so I Googled around and found out that it can only be done by Lua. I have installed `nginx-extras` and am now using the following script:

```
        location ~ '\.php$' {
             location ~ ^/webservice/ {
               access_by_lua_block
               {
                   ngx.req.read_body()
                   local body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
                   if body
                      body = string.gsub(body, "SOAP-ENV", "soap")
                   end
                   ngx.req.set_body_data(body)
               }
             }
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;

             include fastcgi_params;
             fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
             $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
             fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
             fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        }
```

It appears body is always nil. I am using SOAP UI for placing the SOAP request. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why would you use `access_by_lua`? That's for the access phase of the request handling, aka. it tecides whether the client is allowed to make that request. What you want is `body_filter_by_lua` (see [readme](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/#body_filter_by_lua_block))

Comment: Actually, never mind that last comment; it seems like openresty already makes the body available during the access phase after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lua_need_request_body on;` did the trick. See official [documentation](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_need_request_body).

Answer (score 2):

*[note to self: no more quick-reading while having lunch]*

There is a `then` missing after the `if body` and you want to use `ngx.re.gsub` (I don't really know why). After these 2 changes I got it working on my lab:

```lua
                   ngx.req.read_body()
                   local body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
                   if body then
                      body = ngx.re.gsub(body, "SOAP-ENV", "soap")
                   end
                   ngx.req.set_body_data(body)
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortuantely sub_filter replaces the response, in this case I want to replace the request body.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that wasn't the issue. I already tried without the if statement. From what I know the SOAP call is just XML send using POST in the body of the request, but somehow it is not returned when using `ngx.req.get_body_data()`.

Comment: Perhaps the request's body size exceeds the amount nginx is able to store in memory (`client_body_buffer_size`). See [ngx.req.get_body_data Doc](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_body_data). There are also some hints on how to go around this...
PS: The code is definitely working with a small post body...

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my opening post, but I already found that and tried adding ` client_body_buffer_size 50M;` (which is much larger then the actual request), so that didn't seem to work either. We did found a workaround now (totally outside nginx). So we are good for now. Thanks again for your help!